# Best way to read out URL Variable

Tags: php, url, get

i got a little Question for you. I need to read out my URL to show out a Customer Page. What is the best way to do that? I thought about something like this but it doesn't work.

```
//list-kunden (eng list-customer )
<td><a class="btn btn-default" href="kunde-anzeigen.php/?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" role="button">Kunde anzeigen</a></td>
//kunde-anzeigen (customer-show )
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

Right now i just get this

> Error: Object not found!

So he doesnt look up the URL right

Comment: Hallo. Its not totally clear what you're asking... Or at least I'm not sure. Can you be a bit more precise? Also you have a error in your `href` ... you have a `/` after the anzeigen.php, what shouldn't be there. `anzeigen.php?id=value` would be the right format. If you wish we can open a chatroom and look at your problem.. (I'm speaking german, so may it helps...)

Comment: i cant open a chatroom but maybe you can..^^ and yeah in german it would be a lot easier. Im asking for a good and safe way to get out the id field in my URL so i can use it for a customer page for each of the customers

Comment: Join me :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142259/twinfriends-morning-help

Comment: cant talk with u since i dont got 20 Reputations :(

Comment: Aber ich kann ja hier auf Deutsch die Frage nochmal stellen. Ich habe das Problem das ich eine Kunden Seite erstellen will welche sich die ID des Kunden aus der URL zieht.. Welches sich wiederrum aus einer Kundenliste über den Button (siehe oben) die ID zieht.

Comment: Okay. I see. So I think the `$row['id']` comes from a database query. When you hover the link with your mouse, you should see int the left bottom corner of your browser something like kunde-anzeigen.php/?id=234 (random number). So the `$_GET` in the next line does not work because you haven't loaded this URL yet. Add `if(isset($_GET["id"])) { $_GET["id"]; }` and it should work when you klick on the link.

Comment: Thanks. Could you look up the other answer got another Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $row['id'] is a number or string, it will work - if you remove the slash from the href. New href would be:

```
kunde-anzeigen.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>
```

This got pointed out by Twinfriends in the first comment; you should still follow its advice in the last comment, because never ever use a Parameter in your code without checking, it could get changed by the user.

So the code in kunde-anzeigen.php would be:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    echo $_GET['id'];
}
```

Or, if you use php7, it could be like:

```
echo $_GET['id']??'default';
```

Comment: Ok thats working now thanks. But i got another Question. I need this Variable to insert it into a Foreign Key into the Server Colum in my Database. I saved it into $id but when i call to /server/create the Variable equals nothing... Does it delete the Variable if i call to the new File? The file where i call $id is kunde-anzeigen.php and in there is the file sidebar-kunde included. But when i call <li><a href="../kunden/server/create.php?kundenid=<?php $id ?>">Neuer Server</a></li> its like i said above

Comment: Could you then please accept the answer?
What do you mean by call? If you href to another page, yes, the variables are only permanent between requests if they are in the session. If you use an include to "call" another file, the variables persist in the scope. Edit: ahh now i see, you must use <?php echo $id ?>, you forgot the echo, or just <?=$id?>

Comment: $kunden_id = $_GET['kundenid']; and the Database is id of kunden to kunden_id in server both int 11

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`doku`.`server`, CONSTRAINT `kunde->server` FOREIGN KEY (`kunden_id`) REFERENCES `kunden` (`id`))